# Go assert.Equal some interface with time.Time object inside

Tags: unit-testing, go, testify, go-testing

I am trying to check if the returned data equals the expectation

Here is my function:

```
func extractData(payload string) (interface{}, time.Time, error) {

    eventTime := gjson.Get(payload, "data.eventDateTime").String()

    dateTime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00", eventTime)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, time.Time{}, fmt.Errorf("Date Time Error: %w", err)
    }

    body := data.Body{
        EventTime: dateTime,
    }

    return body, dateTime, nil
}
```

This is the unit test I wrote for it:

```
func TestExtractData(t *testing.T) {

    tests := []struct {
        Name           string
        Payload        string
        ExpectedOutput interface{}
    }{
        {
            Name:    "test-2",
            Payload: "{\"data\":\"2020-11-02T10:44:48+01:00\"}",
            ExpectedOutput: data.Body{
                EventTime: time.Date(2020, 11, 2, 10, 44, 48, 0, time.FixedZone("CET", 3600)),
            },
        },
    }

    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.Name, func(t *testing.T) {
            data, _, _ := extractData(tt.Payload)
            assert.Equal(t, tt.ExpectedOutput, data)
        })
    }
}
```

The test is failing, it outputs:

```
{ 2020-11-02 10:44:48 +0100 CET} does not equal { 2020-11-02 10:44:48 +0100 CET}
```

I believe the problem is in `TimeZone`, but I struggles to write the test code.

I don't want to test it using `time.Equal`, because my `data.Body` does not always contains the `eventTime` element.

I tried (by temporary use type not interface):

```
if !tt.ExpectedOutput.EventTime.Equal(data.EventTime) {
    //throw error
}
```

and it works.

I also i tried:

```
if !reflect.DeepEqual(tt.ExpectedOutput.EventTime, data.EventTime) {
    t.Errorf("extractData() output = %v, want = %v",data,tt.ExpectedOutput)
}
```

The code above fails.

Comment: The choices seem pretty clear, either write the comparison manually, or use a comparator with more features like [`go-cmp`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/go-cmp/cmp)

Answer (score 7):

You're partially correct that the time zone can make two `time.Time` instances representing the same time fail equality. It can also be that because [since go 1.9](https://golang.org/doc/go1.9#library), `time.Time` also includes wall time to make all comparisons safe, `time.Time` literals such as your `ExpectedOutput` field will never contain this wall time, so are "different".

Your best solution is probably to compare the time using `assert.WithinDuration()` (I assume you are using `github.com/stretchr/testify/assert`?):

```golang
package kata

import (
    "testing"
    "time"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestTime(t *testing.T) {
    format := "2006-01-02 15:04:05.999999999 -0700 MST"
    time1 := time.Now()
    time2, err := time.Parse(format, time1.Format(format))
    assert.NoError(t, err)
    t.Log(time1)
    t.Log(time2)
    assert.Equal(t, time1, time2)             // fails
    assert.WithinDuration(t, time1, time2, 0) // passes
}
```